# Sparql Group Entire Objects into List

Tags: sparql

I have a list of restaurants and want to return them grouped in lists by two identifiers. The response would look this this in JSON:

```
[
    {
        "restaurantChainId": "1",
        "restaurantTypeId": "001",
        "restaurantList": [
            {
                "restaurantId": "1-1",
                "restaurantChainId": "1",
                "restaurantTypeId": "001",
                "restaurant name": "Pizza Place London"
                "restaurant location": "London"
            },
            {
                "restaurantId": "1-2",
                "restaurantChainId": "1",
                "restaurantTypeId": "001",
                "restaurant name": "Pizza Place Birmingham"
                "restaurant location": "Birmingham"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "restaurantChainId": "1",
        "restaurantTypeId": "002",
        "restaurantList": [
            {
                "restaurantId": "1-3",
                "restaurantChainId": "1",
                "restaurantTypeId": "002",
                "restaurant name": "Pizza Place Manchester"
                "restaurant location": "Manchester"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "restaurantChainId": "2",
        "restaurantTypeId": "002",
        "restaurantList": [
            {
                "restaurantId": "2-1",
                "restaurantChainId": "2",
                "restaurantTypeId": "002",
                "restaurant name": "Taco Town London"
                "restaurant location": "London"
            },
            {
                "restaurantId": "2-2",
                "restaurantChainId": "2",
                "restaurantTypeId": "002",
                "restaurant name": "Taco Town Newcastle"
                "restaurant location": "Newcastle"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So that an object in the array has a list where each in the list shares the `restaurantChainId` and the `restaurantTypeId`.

I have tried the following group_concat query:

```
SELECT ?restaurantChainId (GROUP_CONCAT(?restaurantTypeId; SEPARATOR=", ") AS ?restaurantTypeIdList)
WHERE {
  ?restaurant <http://example.com/terms#docType> "restaurant" ;
       <http://example.com/terms#restaurantTypeId> ?restaurantTypeId;
       <http://example.com/terms#institutionFid> ?restaurantChainId .
  FILTER (strstarts(str(?restaurantTypeId), '00'))
} GROUP BY ?restaurantChainId
```

But obviously this is just producing a list `restaurantTypeId` for each `restaurantChainId`. So it has grouped things correctly. I have things in the correct groups but I only have the id list for each restaurant where I actually want all related information of that restaurant. I don't really know how to go about this. Is it possible?

### Improved Query

```
SELECT ?restaurantChainId  (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?restaurantTypeId; SEPARATOR=", ") AS ?restaurantTypeIdList) (GROUP_CONCAT(?restaurant; SEPARATOR=", ") AS ?restaurant)
WHERE {
  ?restaurant <http://example.co.uk/terms#docType> "restaurant" ;
       <http://example.co.uk/terms#swiftbic> ?restaurantTypeId;
       <http://example.co.uk/terms#institutionFid> ?restaurantChainId ;
       <http://example.co.uk/terms#fid> ?officeId .
      
  FILTER (strstarts(str(?restaurantTypeId), 'ABA'))
} GROUP BY ?restaurantChainId ?restaurantTypeId
```

And here is the current result:

```
{
  "head" : {
    "vars" : [ "restaurantChainId", "restaurantTypeIdList", "restaurant" ]
  },
  "results" : {
    "bindings" : [ {
      "restaurantChainId" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "XYZ"
      },
      "restaurantTypeIdList" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "ABA3"
      },
      "restaurant" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "http://example.co.uk/restaurant/XYZ-4, http://example.co.uk/restaurant/XYZ-5, http://example.co.uk/restaurant/XYZ-6"
      }
    }, {
      "restaurantChainId" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "ABC"
      },
      "restaurantTypeIdList" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "ABA1"
      },
      "restaurant" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "http://example.co.uk/restaurant/ABC-14, http://example.co.uk/restaurant/ABC-15, http://example.co.uk/restaurant/ABC-4"
      }
    }, {
      "restaurantChainId" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "XYZ"
      },
      "restaurantTypeIdList" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "ABA1"
      },
      "restaurant" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "http://example.co.uk/restaurant/XYZ-2, http://example.co.uk/restaurant/XYZ-1"
      }
    }, {
      "restaurantChainId" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "XYZ"
      },
      "restaurantTypeIdList" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "ABA2"
      },
      "restaurant" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "http://example.co.uk/restaurant/XYZ-3"
      }
    }, {
      "restaurantChainId" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "ABC"
      },
      "restaurantTypeIdList" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "ABA2"
      },
      "restaurant" : {
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "http://example.co.uk/restaurant/ABC-9"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

So the actually groupings are correct and I have the uri for each restaurant but I don't know how to get information specifically related to them.

Comment: is this the result you get right now? Or what you would like to get? I mean, you need JSON-LD as response format, or not? And that needs a SPARQL contruct query if I'm not totally wrong.

Comment: And for the JSON formatting then you'll need a triple store/SPARQL engine that supports [JSON-LD Framing](https://www.w3.org/2018/jsonld-cg-reports/json-ld-framing/)

Comment: @AKSW I have updated my answer to include a slightly improved query and the output of that query.

Comment: Ok, that's SPARQL JSON  - but what is missing there. I mean, it contains exactly what you queried for. If you also want data about restaurants, I highly recommend to use a SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` query and use JSON-LD as response type.

Comment: I also don't think it's possible with a single SELECT query. I mean, on the one hand you want grouping, but on the other hand you want data for each entity inside a group. Sometimes it's much simpler to use (a) multiple queries or even more often it's much better to (b) do the data processing on the client side.